# Upload image to amazonS3 issue Froala

Tags: php, angularjs, froala

Currently i am integrating froala in my project (which is in angualarJs and laravel). I need to upload the image to amazonS3. But i have some issues with the amazoneS3 path. Here is my code.

with in the view,

```
<textarea id="froala-sample-2" ng-init="article.description = article.description || ''" ng-model="article.description"></textarea>
```

I changed the fileUploadToS3 to true in file.min.js.([as per the docs.](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options))

with in the angular controller

```
Data.get('{{url}}').then(function(data){
var dta         = angular.fromJson(data);
$scope.sign     = dta.sign;
$scope.policy   = dta.policy;
$scope.bucket   = dta.bucket;
$scope.region   = dta.region;
$scope.keystart = dta.keystart;
$scope.acl      = dta.acl;
$scope.accessKey= dta.key;

$('#froala-sample-2').froalaEditor({
    enter: $.FroalaEditor.ENTER_P,
    imageUploadToS3: {
        bucket: $scope.bucket,
        region: $scope.region,
        keyStart: $scope.keystart,
        params: {
            acl: $scope.acl,
            AWSAccessKeyId: $scope.accessKey,
            policy: $scope.policy,
            signature: $scope.sign,
        }
    }
})
.on('froala.image.uploadedToS3', function (e, editor, link, key, response) {
    console.log ('S3 Link:', link);
    console.log ('S3 Key:', key);
});}, function (error) {});
```

here iam creating the signature and policy

```
public function createSignature() {
// Set date timezone.
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');

$bucket     = '-bucket-';
$region     = '-region-';
$keyStart   = '-keystart-';
$acl        = '-acl-';


$accessKeyId = $_SERVER['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'];
$secret      = $_SERVER['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'];

$policy      = base64_encode(
    json_encode(
        array(

            'expiration' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z', strtotime('+1 day')),
            'conditions' => array(
                array('bucket' => $bucket),
                array('acl' => $acl),
                array('success_action_status' => '201'),
                array('x-requested-with' => 'xhr'),
                array('starts-with', '$key', $keyStart),
                array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', '') // accept all files
                ) )));

$aData['policy']    = $policy;
$aData['sign']      = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $policy, $secret, true));
$aData['bucket']    = $bucket;
$aData['region']    = $region
$aData['keystart']  = $keyStart;
$aData['acl']       = $acl;
$aData['key']       = $accessKeyId;
return json_encode($aData);}
```

When i uploading an image, i got the following issue:
OPTIONS ***https://undefined.amazonaws.com/undefined net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.***
Somebody please tell me how can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `imageUploadToS3` object is populated correctly:

```
imageUploadToS3: {
  bucket: $scope.bucket,
  region: $scope.region,
  keyStart: $scope.keystart,
  params: {
    acl: $scope.acl,
    AWSAccessKeyId: $scope.accessKey,
    policy: $scope.policy,
    signature: $scope.sign,
  }
}
```

From https://undefined.amazonaws.com/undefined error, I assume that at least `$scope.bucket` and `$scope.region` are undefined.

Also you can check Froala PHP SDK ( https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor-php-sdk ) and its documentation ( https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/php ) The SDK will do the Amazon S3 file upload for you.

Or you can inspire on how the signature is created: https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/FroalaEditor/S3.php . And here is the documentation on how to use it https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/php/file-s3-upload .

Hope it helps.

Comment: is this resolved ? I'm having the same issue, using rails.